# android: Customizing Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, customization, android-spinner

I am trying to create a custom Spinner and I am encountering difficulties doing so.

This is the effect I am trying to achieve:
[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFitY.png)

However I find it very difficult to set the background colour of the Spinner to black. I have tried setting the `android:background` property but when I do so the Spinner disappears completely as if the height was set to 0. I would really appreciate any help.

Also, here is the code I am using:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        />
```

Comment: You'll have to use a custom adapter for the spinner. That will give you the liberty to use a different drop down and normal view resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this: in layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />  //your down arrow on right side
</RelativeLayout>
```

For drawable border:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <corners
        android:radius="0dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

For spinner textview color use a custom layout for item:`spinner_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"         
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
```

in Java: use the layout

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

Comment: This answer is correct. However when selecting the spinner and opening it the background is white, and so no options are displayed. Why is that?